# Conditional static_assert

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Is there an elegant way to perform a *conditional* static_assert in c++11

For example:

```
template <class T>
class MyClass
{
    COMPILE_TIME_IF( IsTypeBuiltin<T>::value)
       static_assert(std::is_floating_point<T>::value, "must be floating pt");
};
```

Comment: Have you considered using the && operator or is this not a viable alternative?

Comment: && would work, maybe I should've rephrase the question as a 'compile time if' based on type

Comment: @bendervader `std::is_integral<T>` and `std::is_floating_point<T>` are exclusive. What is it that you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to enable the static assert if and only if the type is integral. If the user passes their own class, I do not want to assert

Comment: @bendervader But, if `T` is integral, it can't be floating point.

Comment: @bendervader Perhaps you meant something like `static_assert(!std::is_arithmetic<T>::value || std::is_floating_point<T>::value, "must be floating pt");`

Comment: I edited the question. You are right. I might to say a fundamental type

Comment: @Biffen that actually works can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple boolean logic within `static_assert()` should do it:

```
static_assert(
  (!std::is_fundamental<T>::value)
  || std::is_floating_point<T>::value,
  "must be floating pt"
);
```

I.e. `T` is either *not* fundamental or it's floating point. In other words: If `T` *is* fundamental it must also be floating point.